# Word to refer to the person who creates something that gets reused or remixed?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a noun to describe the role of "Person A" in the following scenario.

1. Person A makes a digital project (e.g. a video game, animation, video, etc).
2. Person B creates a digital project using Person A's project, either parts or the whole thing.

I am calling Person B's project a ***remix*** of Person A's project. 
Also, I am calling Person B a ***remixer***.

What would you call Person A? Some of the terms I've used are but that I am not 100% happy with are:

- **remixee**. I like this one but its a bit obscure and easy to visually confuse with the term remixer.
- **original creator**. This is easy to understand but it's two words and it has the problem that it makes it seem as if the remixer is not original, which has a subtle but negative undertone.
- **originator**.

Other ideas?

Comment: Interesting question. In a sense this word would be the mirror image of the plagiarist.

Comment: I don't have any votes left for today, but _progenitor_ is the best response you've received thus far, IMO.

Comment: @ogerard: well, plagiarist has a negative connotation. In this case I'm trying to acknowledge the positive aspects of remixing and come up with something more neutral.

Comment: Person A is the meme'ist and person B is the meme'er.

Comment: As an aside, the chain of derivatives from an original is often described as the work's *providence*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [copyright law](http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html), party B's work is called "derivative". The previous work is called "preexisting", so he could be described as the "preexisting author".

Answer (score 11):

[progenitor](http://www.wordnik.com/words/progenitor)

> 1. An originator of a line of descent; a precursor.
> 2. An originator; a founder: progenitors of the new music.

Comment: @pageman: please note that on SE sites, leaving a comment saying "+1" means that you have actually upvoted the post (which in this case you haven't).

Comment: Thanks. I am not 100% sold on this one but it is definitely a very good alternative.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try out *first party* or *principal*.

Comment: Principal Author sounds unambiguous and clear to me.  First Party sounds like contractual mumbo-jumbo.

Answer (score 3):

Creator?

Source?

Author?

Interesting question :-)

Comment: Source could work. The others not so much because the remixer is also a creator and an author.

Comment: I like _source_ as well. It's also the name of a popular hip-hop [magazine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Source_(magazine)), a genre known for its musical sampling and remixing.

Answer (score 3):

These are reasonable multi-word stabs:

- "Author of the original work"
- "Original Author"
- "Principal Author"
- "Prima facie Author"

I like your idea "originator" but it lacks zing, and it lacks the implied Authorial ownership, and thus, if you really really want to drop it down to a single word, I can only suggest using a term which preserves the dignity of their essential ownership:

- "Author"
- "Creator"

Then, for the derivatives, call them "Mixologists", "Mashupologists" or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Original Content Provider
Original Copyright Holder (from a Creative Commons perspective)

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is always *victim*.