# Word for the person who originally said a quote

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe the person who said a quote?

Comment: Related: _[Word to refer to the person who creates something that gets reused or remixed?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/22465/5822)_

Comment: Most times, we just call them ***source***.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use `originator`. The online Merriam-Webster dictionary also lists `quotee`.

Comment: +1. I was expecting a more specific word, though.