# What do you call a person who started something that is later followed by everyone?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, epithet-requests

What do you call a person who started something that is later followed by everyone? For example, someone started to stay late at night till 8 p.m. and later everyone started to stay till 8 p.m..

Comment: Related: [Word to refer to the person who creates something that gets reused or remixed?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/22465/5822)

Comment: You call them a hipster.

Comment: The thing can be called a portent, but calling the thing starter a portenter sounds strange.

Comment: In tech we use "early adopter," although there's no implication that others have yet followed suit.

Comment: I just wanted to tack on a blog post I saw related to this topic, which poses some terminology specifically dealing with the notion of subcultures. It isn't strictly what's meant, here, but it definitely addresses a subset of the topic: http://meaningness.com/metablog/geeks-mops-sociopaths

Answer (score 122, accepted):

A [*trend-setter*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trend-setter) or [*trendsetter*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trendsetter):

> someone who starts a trend, or makes one more popular

The other answers on this page have a couple other fine suggestions — and a [thesaurus lookup](http://thesaurus.com/browse/trendsetter) turns up more suggestions still —, but be aware that some of them require additional quali­fication. For example, it's typically "a harbinger *of something*", or "a precursor *to something*". So you won't be able to just say "he is a harbinger" and leave it at that; likewise, "he is a pre­cursor" will only raise questions if no further context is supplied. "He is a trendsetter", on the other hand, is perfectly self-explanatory and self-sufficient.

Answer (score 32):

*Pioneer* is the word for that, but in this particular example, it may not be a good fit. *Pioneer* carries a positive emotion, and I would not use it for something perceived as negative (like staying late at work).

Comment: Pioneer is some who does it first, but not necessarily someone who is then followed. Eg the Wright brothers pioneered aviation, but not many of us fly (pilot) aircraft

Answer (score 23):

I also rather like *forerunner* for someone who starts a trend — sometimes even *harbinger* or *herald*, depending.

The thing about *harbinger* and *herald* is that those portend (or *augur*) something upcoming if not imminent, while a *forerunner* is just ahead of his time.

Comment: harbinger ... of DOOM! (sorry, couldn't resist.. )

Answer (score 23):

My first answer was a *trailblazer*.

Noun
A person who makes a new track through wild country.
A pioneer; an innovator.

Comment: I think trailblazer would only be being used sarcastically in this context, though. It implies a positive effect rather than staying late at work, which implies negative.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe also [*initiator*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/initiator) could fit?

> one who initiates

Answer (score 10):

*Bellwether*. Quoting from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellwether):

> A **bellwether** is any entity in a given arena that serves to create
>   or influence trends or to presage future happenings.
>
> The term is derived from the Middle English *bellewether* and refers to
>   the practice of placing a bell around the neck of a castrated ram (a
>   *wether*) leading his flock of sheep. The movements of the flock could
>   be noted by hearing the bell before the flock was in sight.

Comment: I have never heard a bellwether used in the context of a person. The modern usage with which I am familiar is when describing the long bond, which is the 30-year maturity U.S. Treasury bond. The T-bond, or 10 year T-note are bellwether securities. If you know of another use, applicable to a person, I would be very curious for details. Bellwether is a great word.

Comment: This is specifically the sense in which Connie Willis uses the word in her book *Bellwether*: a habitual, effortless trendsetter.

Comment: I'm still searching, can only find bellwether as a trend indicator, or bellwether stocks, or in the context of a news information source. Dictionary definitions say "entity" or "person" but I can't find examples of such.

Comment: @librik No, I don't think so. I checked several blurbs for **Bellwether**, as well as the article precis in Wikipedia. The novel involves scientists experimenting with sheep as bellwethers for deriving a forecasting methodology, applicable to human behavior. According to plot summaries of the book, human beings are bellwethers only in the sense that fads are started by a person or persons in the crowd, who without conscious intent or realization, happen to be a little ahead of the rest.

Comment: OK, if you haven't read the book, you won't know the punchline: there is one wacky young woman who, just following her own inclinations, ends up as the leading edge for all the fads in the story.  If Pippa's doing it now, everyone else will be doing it soon.  She's the Bellwether of the title.

Comment: @librik I just read 3 reviews of the book. Flip is the name of the assistant, not Pippa. Pippa is a character in Robert Browning's **Pippa Passes**. Flip is a nickname for Phillipa, presumably, thus the allusion and similarities between Flip in the Willis novel with Pippa. I am not convinced that Flip, or Pippa, was a bellwether of human behavior, not in the way asked by the question, which I think implies deliberate choice not accidental whimsy.

Answer (score 7):

I felt the need to float "Innovator" given *editor*'s suggestion of "early adopter", mostly to make clear that, within frameworks for understanding adoption rates, *innovators* are generally considered to be the first to adopt the innovation and are themselves *followed* by the early adopters. Innovators cast the die or blaze the trail, and early adopters may or may not follow. There's a media-related term (particularly in advertising/marketing/PR) "[opinion leader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_leadership)" which is used as part of the theoretical construct for how new [innovations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_innovations) spread. It may also be useful in this case for explaining the idea that people who aren't directly involved in the act of innovating  are perceived as a more-reliable (i.e., impartial) bellwether by the average eventual adopter.

Answer (score 6):

You could also, depending on your style and context, use the word [*precursor*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/precursor?s=t):

> a person, animal, or thing that goes before and indicates the approach of someone or something else; harbinger

Two example sentences related to original poster's request:

> - When I saw everybody's eyes on Jeremy as he glided across the hall in those "heelies" things, I knew he was the precursor to a new fad.
> - Janette is the precursor to the new trend at the office to wear silly pins on casual Fridays.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! It would be helpful if you could edit your answer to include a definition from a dictionary that fits the OP's word request. Any examples of your word in a quote would be welcome also.

Comment: I like precursor as a choice! I think of it primarily in the context of chemistry though. As @KristinaLopez said, it would be great to have a definition, and if possible, an example of precursor used in context as part of your answer.

Comment: @FeralOink Precursors also occur in literature and movies and the likes.

Answer (score 4):

[*Instigator*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/instigator) might be appropriate in some contexts, if it's clear that others are now involved.

> a person who brings about or initiates something

Answer (score 3):

*Avant-garde*. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avant-garde),

> **Avant-garde** ([...] from French, “advance guard” or “[vanguard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanguard_%28disambiguation%29)”[<sup>[1]</sup>](http://dictionary.reference.com/search?q=avant-garde)) is a French term used in English as a noun or adjective to refer to people or works that are experimental or innovative, particularly with respect to art, culture, and politics.
>
> Avant-garde represents a pushing of the boundaries of what is accepted as the norm or the status quo, primarily in the cultural realm…

The last sentence suggests that the behavior of the avant-garde is eventually followed by at least some people.

Comment: I have to admit I find this works better as an adjective than as a substantive.

Answer (score 2):

I would call them a *progenitor*.

Answer (score 1):

In some contexts, *pathfinder* would be appropriate, but not generally.

Answer (score 0):

*Flag bearer* will be an apt term.

Answer (score 0):

I would call them an *initiator*. According to the OED:

> initiator |ɪˈnɪʃɪeɪtə| *a person or thing that initiates someone or something.*